# How to check whether a certain field is present in AWS IoT message or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I have two IoT rules in which one rule stores valid data to a table in DynamoDB, and other rule which stores invalid data to another table in DynamoDB.

This works fine as long as all fields are present. But if any field is not present IoT throws: **Error while evaluating where clause: Undefined result**

For example here is expected message:

```
{
    field_1: 'value1',
    field_2: 'value2',
    field_3: 'value3'
}
```

SQL rule for Valid Data:

`select field_1 as x, field_2 as y, field_3 as z WHERE cast(field_1 as Int) > 10`

SQL rule for Invalid Data:

`select field_1 as x, field_2 as y, field_3 as z WHERE NOT ( cast(field_1 as Int) > 10 )`

If any field is missing as shown below, above rule won't work.

```
{
    field_1: 'value1',
    field_2: 'value2'
}
```

What is the way to detect whether a certain field is present or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IsUndefined() function to do that.
For example you can do something like that in the WHERE statement:

```
SELECT field_1 as x, field_2 as y, field_3 as z FROM 'topic' WHERE IsUndefined(field_1) = False AND IsUndefined(field_2) = False AND IsUndefined(field_3) = False
```

With this statement the rule will no trigger if one of the 3 fields is missing.